# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on dequeuing cell from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uicollectionview

I have a problem when dequeuing a UICollectionView cell from the storyboard.
I have a view controller with a collection view as one of the subviews. The VC is set as the collection view's data source and delegate. The collection view has a couple of prototype cells with identifiers set.

When doing this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sizingCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:nil];
}
```

I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on the self.sizingCell line.
Interestingly, when I created a new test project with a view controller containing a collection view and did the same thing in viewDidLoad, the collection view's cell was created with no issues.
Did anyone else run into a similar issue?

Comment: Why are you dequeuing a cell in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: indexPath should be a non nil value I imagine. Best to do any cell sizing the first time it is needed: when `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called. Then you have an indexPath you can use.

Comment: Indexpath can indeed be nil. In my test project I did it the same way and it worked. I'm dequeuing the cell in view did load so that I have a cell that I can populate in heightForRowAtIndex. If I dequeue the cell in rowForHeight, it finishes calculating the size (but will be no different from default size though it should) and then crashes by sending a setFrameForItem to a deallocated flow item. If I set the estimated flow item height for the collectionView's flow layout, it crashes by blowing the stack :(. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I'm really starting to hate collection views.